# Как получить данные во View при выполнении create с не связанной на прямую таблицу C# Asp .net entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, razor

Здраствуйте.Я хочу настроить свое приложение что бы при создании нового поля в таблице PareSubgroup у меня во View в поле выбора при создании возвращало не id с таблицы Schedule а discipline_name с таблицы subject.
[image: вот как оно выглядит]

```
 public IActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewData["Pare_Id"] = new SelectList(_context.Schedules, "Id", "Id");
        ViewData["Subgroup_Id"] = new SelectList(_context.Subgroups, "Id", "Id");
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Pare_Id,Subgroup_Id")] PareSubgroup pareSubgroup)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(pareSubgroup);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        ViewData["Pare_Id"] = new SelectList(_context.Schedules, "Id", "Id", pareSubgroup.Pare_Id);
        ViewData["Subgroup_Id"] = new SelectList(_context.Subgroups, "Id", "Id", pareSubgroup.Subgroup_Id);
        return View(pareSubgroup);
    }
```

```html
@{ ViewData["Title"] = "Create"; }

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>PareSubgroup</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Create">
      <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Pare_Id" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="Pare_Id" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Pare_Id"></select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Subgroup_Id" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="Subgroup_Id" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Subgroup_Id"></select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts { @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");} }
```

[image: Модель данных]

Comment: На схеме я вижу таблицу `Pare`, а в коде нет к ней обращения. Зато в коде я вижу `_context.Schedules`. | Очевидно, нужно написать linq-запрос, который джойнит две таблицы. Какой именно сказать не могу, т. к. не вижу всех связей.

Comment: Я исправил модель данных . Schedules это dbset от Pare. По сути я пытаюсь при помощи следуюющей строки получить имя дисциплины с таблицы Schedule
{ViewData["Pare_Id"] = new SelectList(_context.Schedules.Include(s=>s.Subject), "Id", "Discipline_Name");
} 
Но у меня появляется ошибка  "Non a public member когда я смотрю что в переменной". И "Object reference not set to an instance of an object "когда передается во View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я разобрался . Я просто в моделе Schedule создал поле которое получает связанную информацию.

В самой моделе добавил поле :

```
[ValidateNever]
    public string Description { get { return Subject.Discipline_Name; } }
```

Контроллер

```
ViewData["Pare_Id"] = new SelectList(_context.Schedules.Include(s=>s.Subject), "Id", "Description");
```